# Which fantasy worlds can be freely used in new work without a license?

Tags: world-building

There are lots of different fantasy worlds depicted in fiction. In general, due to copyright, a license is required from the original creator of the fiction to publish a new story set in that universe (for example, you need to get LucasArts to agree to make a new Star Wars book). Are there any examples of fantasy worlds where this is not true?

Comment: This is a list question, where the answer can be a near-infinite list, a kind of question disallowed on Stack Exchange sites. Closing.

Comment: But theoretically it could be answered with a single class of worlds. For example mythology. Mythology can't be copyrighted because the copyrights have not existed in ancient times (what a luck for us). You can use the mythology as much as you want.

Comment: Of course, ‘fantasy’ is not exactly equivalent with ‘mythology’, but you could easily scrub out mention of “fantasy” in this question and you wouldn't broaden it by that much.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [Man-Kzin Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Kzin_Wars) represents one such world.  The series started as a short story by Larry Niven, but several more stories have sprung up mostly written by people who are not Larry Niven.

I have also read books by Mercedes Lackey that are collections of short stories written in her Valdamar world by other authors.

I think if you have a particular universe that you want to use for a story, you need to do some research and see if that author or publisher allows for other people to contribute to that universe.